# Wildfly Swarm Restfull API not working when called from outside localhost

Tags: cordova, ionic2, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I am starting with Wildfly Swarm and I built this API to be used from an app developed with Ionic 2, the API works fine when testing it on my own PC and also with Postman.

When I try to run the app on an actual device, it just won't get any response at all. I also tested Postman from another PC on the same network, doesn't work either.

I know I am not giving much of details, this is because I don't know what pieces of code I should add here, so If you need any detail, just let me know.

Comment: Didn't you test the app on the browser using `Ionic server`?

Comment: Yea, I did, it works this way, but with `ionic run android` it doesnt

Comment: You can do remote debugging then? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Wildfly Swarm will listen on port 8080 by default.  Are you sure that port 8080 is not being blocked by your computer/firewall?

Comment: @stdunbar how can I test that theory?

Comment: First, on the machine that is running the Wildfly service, make sure that Wildfly is listening on all interfaces - Unix/Mac OS/X - run `netstat -na | grep LIST`, Windows just `netstat -na`.  Look for a line that looks something like `tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN`.  The key is the `*.8080`.  If it says something like `127.0.0.1:8080` then it will only be accessible from localhost.  Let's start there.

Comment: WF Swarm should bind to all interfaces on whatever port you've defined, or 8080 by default. I suspect as @stdunbar stated, the most likely problem is port 8080 is not accessible outside the machine it's running on

Comment: Swarm will normally try to bind to IPv6 localhost [::]:8080. You can force it to bind to a certain interface on startup with property swarm.bind.address